# С#: ошибка доступа к файлу - файл занят другим процессом

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Добрый день.

У меня появилась ситуация, когда 2 потока пытаются записать в файл свои логи.

Процедура записи в лог:

```
private object threadLock = new object();
...
    private void AddTextToFile(string log)
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            StreamWriter _testData = null;
            try
            {
                _testData = new StreamWriter(_path, true, System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode);
                _testData.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now, log));
                _testData.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_testData != null)
                {
                    _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
                    _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Маркер блокировки есть, как избежать этой ошибки?
Текст ошибки:

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\Logs\SmsGate\SmsInspector.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.

**По идее, ее не должно быть. Что я делаю не правильно?
Спасибо.**

Comment: класс, в котором все это объявлено - singleton? threadLock у вас случайно не должнен быть static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в этом коде. Ваш код написан правильно.
Вы не закрываете файл где-то в другом месте. Или другой поток использует другой `threadLock`.

---

P.S.: Зачем так сложно, можно ведь просто

```
lock (threadLock)
{
    File.AppendAllText(
        _path,
        string.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now, log),
        Encoding.Unicode);
}
```